# Returning PHP results to original html page

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ajax

I would like to return the value `$newsum` to the col div which comes from a php calculation to db results. I would like to keep the html and php files separate. However, when that is done I dont get the results on the index.html page.

I have tried some ajax solutions but none worked yet,

**index.html**

```
<form id="search" action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type='search' name='keywords' value='' style="width:99%;">
    <a href='#col'>
    <input type='hidden' value='Submit' id='submit' name='doSearch' />
    </a>
</form>

<div  id="col"  style="width:100%; margin:0 auto;">
 <script>
 document.write("<?php echo $newsum.$message; ?>");
  </script>
```

**index.php**

```
if($_POST['doSearch'] == 'Submit') 
{
    $value=$_POST['keywords'];
    $newsum= round($total,1);

    if($newsum >= 3.5)
   {

   $message=$newsum.'/5';
   }

    }
```

AJAX

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submit').click(function(){

   $.post("index.php", $("#search").serialize(),  function(response) {
   $('#col').html(response);

    });
    return false;

       });

       });
     </script>
```

Comment: Your PHP file isn't echoing anything? Show us the full relevant code. Probably AJAX is the only way if you insist of not having a PHP page showing the results. So what have you tried?

Comment: Rename `index.php` to another name, have ajax call that PHP file.

Comment: Normally php is used to generate html (among other things...) so keeping the two separated might not be the most efficient solution. You can do everything via ajax of course but I would recommend getting it to work first before you add ajax.

Comment: PHP was designed to be embedded in HTML for dynamic content ;)

Comment: Do you have a good and sound explanation why you would not rename the first file to php, and save yourself alot of hassle?

Comment: I will be using phonegap on this web application. Therefore, I will not be able to use HTML embedded in php which I usually do.

Comment: you've mistaken in **index.php**, you've not printed output of `$newsum`. you've to print it (eg. `echo $newsum`).

Comment: OK. Whats the debugging status of yout AJAX call? Any errors? And still you have to echo out something from index.php.

Answer (score 1):

You missed echoing out the results of the search:

Edit `index.php`

```
if($_POST['doSearch'] == 'Submit') 
{
  $value=$_POST['keywords'];
  $newsum= round($total,1);
  if($newsum >= 3.5)
  {
     $message=$newsum.'/5';
     echo $message; // added
  }
  else 
  {
     echo "Nope"; // this is only to make sure something at all is echoed.
  }
}
```

Then alter your JS:

```
 // submit action instead of click is the way to use form data


 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#search').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("index.php", $("#search").serialize(),  function(response) {
           $('#col').html(response);
        });
     });
  });
 </script>
```

**NOTE**

You added PHP code to your HTML document. This will never work...

```
<script>
 document.write("<?php echo $newsum.$message; ?>"); 
</script>
```

Even if it was a PHP document the variables wouldn't exist as they are set in index.php.

Comment: The results are echoed in html. Once the form is submitted. It stays on index.php and does return to index.html.

Comment: OK, see my edit, add the preventDefault to the form submit action. This prevents the form from loading the index page.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. I modified the js to this but it still takes me to index.php <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
//$('#submit').click(function(){
$('#submit').submit(function(){
   e.preventDefault();
 
$.post("index.php", $("#submit").serialize(),  function(response) {
$('#col').html(response);
//$('#success').hide('slow');
});
return false;
 
});
 
});
</script>

Comment: No you should CHANGE click() to submit() in the javascript part. Also you missed the e as the function variable, then the preventDefault will do nothing! See my edit with full code!